# justfile Unknown start of token in an exported variable

Tags: git, docker, just

My justfile looks like this:

```
export GIT_COMMIT:="$(git show --format="%h" --no-patch)"

docker_build:
    docker build -t some/tag:$GIT_COMMIT -t some/tag:latest .
```

when I run it then I get the following error:

```
export GIT_COMMIT:="$(git show --format="%h" --no-patch)"
                                         ^
```

So basically `just` doesn't like `%`. But it's necessary.

Is there an elegent way to get this to work? I use the GIT_COMMIT variable in a few different places so it would be nice if it was reusable.

So far I'm using this workaround:

```
docker_build:
    GIT_COMMIT="$(git show --format="%h" --no-patch)";  docker build -t some/tag:$GIT_COMMIT .
    docker build -t some/tag:latest .
```

But it gets a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your justfile is not the percent sign, it's that you're using the same type of quotes for the outer string and for the inner one. `just` is interpreting the second quote as ending the string, and then doesn't know what to do with the bare `%`.

In this case, because the format is just a single string token long with no spaces, you can simply remove the inner quotes entirely:

```bash
export GIT_COMMIT := "$(git show --format=%h --no-patch)"
```

But if you actually needed the format to have spaces, you could use alternating quotes like this:

```bash
export GIT_COMMIT := "$(git show --format='hash: %h' --no-patch)"
```

Even more options in the [`Just` manual section](https://just.systems/man/en/chapter_28.html?highlight=quote#strings) on strings. You could also [use backticks](https://just.systems/man/en/chapter_32.html) to save the result of the command to the `just` variable instead of saving the string of the unevaluated bash command substitution.